# SSRS Report with date range with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table `FinalQuote` in SQL Server with these columns:

```
Q_hub_from : Perth, Burnie, Sydney etc.
Q_hub_to : Perth, Burnie, Sydney etc.
FinalMargin : 400, 500, 650 etc.
processed_at : Date Time
BookedYN : Yes/No.
```

I want to create a SSRS report which will show the average value of *FinalMargin* for all the rows from a specific *Q_hub_from* to specific *Q_hub_to*. Also wanna show average margin in two columns: one contain average of rows where *BookedYN* is 'YES' and other contain average of rows where *BookedYN* is 'NO'. It is working fine and display required result when I specify a date range(for *processed_at*) in query.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT 
    Q_hub_from, Q_hub_to, 
    ROUND(AVG(FinalMargin), 0) AS Margin,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfQuotesDone, 
    COUNT(CASE BookedYN WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NoOfQuotesBooked,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE BookedYN WHEN 'No' THEN FinalMargin ELSE NULL END), 0) AS MarginWhenNotBooked, 
    ROUND(AVG(CASE BookedYN WHEN 'Yes' THEN FinalMargin ELSE NULL END), 0) AS MarginWhenBooked
FROM 
    FinalQuote
WHERE 
    Q_hub_from <> '' 
    AND Q_hub_from IS NOT NULL
    --AND CAST(processed_at as date) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-10-10'
    AND CAST(processed_at AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
    Q_hub_from, Q_hub_to
ORDER BY 
    Q_hub_from ASC
```

This query produces this output:

[image]

But I want date range to be selected by user, so I added `StartDate` and `EndDate` parameters. My `processed_at` column only mentioned in the `WHERE` clause, not in the `select` statement, so I get this error:

> [rsMissingFieldInDataSet] and [rsErrorReadingDataSetField]

When I add *processed_at* field in DataSet and in GROUP BY clause then it is working (although still displays previous error) but now result is not expected. It shows 2 rows for same *Q_hub_from* and *Q_hub_to*.

Query:

```
SELECT Q_hub_from, Q_hub_to, processed_at, ROUND(AVG(FinalMargin),0) AS Margin,
COUNT(*) AS NoOfQuotesDone, COUNT(case BookedYN when 'Yes' then 1 else null end) AS NoOfQuotesBooked,
ROUND(AVG(case BookedYN when 'No' then FinalMargin else null end),0) AS MarginWhenNotBooked, ROUND(AVG(case BookedYN when 'Yes' then FinalMargin else null end),0) AS MarginWhenBooked
FROM FinalQuote
WHERE Q_hub_from <> '' AND Q_hub_from IS NOT NULL 
AND processed_at between @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY Q_hub_from, Q_hub_to, processed_at
ORDER BY Q_hub_from ASC
```

Output:

[image]

If anyone can help me in achieving the required result that only show 1 row for same *Q_hub_from* to *Q-hub_to* within specific date range(i.e. *processed_at* between *StartDate* and *EndDate*) that will be of great help. I don't wanna display *processed_at* column. I know I am doing something wrong as Its my first time with SSRS.

Feel free to ask if you want to know more. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What are the values you have set for both parameters?

Comment: SSRS warnings like this may not disappear until you close and re-open the project. You should be able to reference columns in the where clause that don't appear in group by or select clauses.

Comment: Suggested reading [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: @akshay parameter values are set to none and no default values.

Comment: Try to assign some values to parameters and make sure parameter type is Date

Comment: and in Dataset properties the parameter values are: [@StartDate] and [@EndDate]

Comment: @Preet like I said before try to assign some values to parameters

Comment: Sorry akshay I am a newbie so no idea what you saying but when I try to change parameter values in available values to select from query then it gives error: report parameter StartDate has default value so forward dependancies are not allowed

Comment: @Used_By_Already I tried reopening the project and removed processed_at from select and group by also from dataset fields but its showing no data in row now

Comment: are you having any more parameters other than startdate and enddate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181649/discussion-between-akshay-and-preet).

Answer (score 3):

If you have not set the values for parametes then try to assign some values to parameters and make sure parameter type is Date.

 You can do it like this, 
create a dataset and put this query 
 `select DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE()) AS StartDate, GETDATE() AS EndDate`

Use this dataset for your both the parameters only in default values section. Don't add it in available values section.

Comment: I have only these two parameters. Sorry I am dumb not able to do that trying to but getting errors:(

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1: AND cast( processed_at as date)  between @StartDate AND @EndDate . As you need to make sure how this column is stored in the tables. If it is DateTime then do an implicit cast to date.
Suggestion 2: on the SSRS make sure you can see your 2 params are params. IF you do then DO NOT SET any values for them. See if you can pick any random range and report renders.
Suggestion 3: if you have to put default values make sure they are either query or best case stored proc generated (sometime like usp_report_params_defaultDateRange). You will give this for default date range. Also type will be date and not int, varchar, etc.
Suggestion 4: If above fail trying building a query and just hardcoding the values so something like Select '2000-01-01' as Q_hub_from, '2001-01-01' as Q_hub_to from table name where cast( processed_at as date)  between @StartDate AND @EndDate and see if it works. Add 1 column at a time and anchor to report and see if it gives you error. (NOTE YOU HAVE TO DELETE .DATA file from your local Bin folder after each local successful run)

Comment: Thanks, problem now solved but all your suggestions are good and I almost tried all of them. My problem solved by deleting all values for params and by deleting filters. thanks again

Comment: you can now start adding them one by one and see where your rdl starts to nag again. Please keep in mind if your doing it locally on bids to navigate to your bin folder and delete the .data file (as it will show stale data). Glad it worked out for ya. Final advice, dont hesitate to close and reopen bids. Data Tools for VS at times is picky.